# custom query and alter data

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have OBJ in my template and its id is used to build the URL. I want to base64 the ID of the OBJ. So in my view I used to do that

```
 objs = ObjsModel.objects.filter( blabla )
 for obj in objs:
     obj.id = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(obj.id))
```

This code works. Unfortunately I have to use RAW SQL for the query. When I use the RAW query the loop is not changing the IDs

```
sql_raw_query = "SELECT * FROM blabla more blabla"
objs = ObjsModel.objects.raw(sql_raw_query)
for obj in objs:
    obj.id = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(obj.id))
```

With that code the IDs are not changed and I don't understand why. How to change the IDs from the view ?

Comment: Are you sure your `objs` collection is not empty?

Comment: yes I am, I get everything the only thing is that the ID is not encoded

Answer (score 1):

Django does not cache the raw queryset, so when you loop over it a second time Django fetches the original objects from the database again.

The solution is to convert the raw queryset to a list.

```
objs = list(ObjsModel.objects.raw(sql_raw_query))
for obj in objs:
    obj.id = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(obj.id))
```